# CSS based on jQuery UI

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'd like create a new CSS class but based (inherited) from `ui-state-default` from jQuery UI. I'd like change some parameters like the backgroud. As background by default it's a picture, in jQuery UI class, I'd like keep all properties except this background.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to somehow "inherit" the `ui-state-default` class. I don't think you can inherit a CSS class like you do in a normal OO language, but you could achieve this effect by creating another class, say, `foo` and use both of the classes in your elements and in your CSS definition.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-state-default foo">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-state-default.foo {
  background: red;
}
```

One thing you need to make sure is that, the css definition has more *specificity* than the one generated by the ThemeRoller. If you are not familiar with the CSS cascading rules, [have a read](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
background{none !important;}
```

Comment: I clarify my question. I want created a class based on a jQuery UI theme class but need to change a property. If I change theme a create one via the ThemeRoller my class as the same characteristics expect the baclground